# Webpart not updating for Read only users

Tags: 2007, web-part, xslt

I have a SharePoint page with Two webparts, one of them is a list displaying the previous months, the other is a xsl webpart that displays the news of the selected month using the url. (like default.aspx?month=november 2012)

The user clicks on a month, the site navigates to the new url and the webpart shows the news.

This works for all for content managers and site administrators, but for users with Read only rights it displays weird behavior, Not properly refreshing the webpart that displays the news.

None of the webparts actually attempt to write anything, so i am baffled why the read only permissions are interfering.

Does anyone know what could be causing this, or have a way to forcibly refresh a webpart?

Edit:
Issue is resolved by giving all authenticated users contribute permissions in the style library (The location of the xsl file). Still looking for a better fix.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a publishing site then make sure that the news items themselves are checked in, approved and published.  Site Owners and Administrators have permission to see unpublished items but generally read-only users do not.

Comment: Giving Contribute rights to all authenticated users in the Style library (where the xsl file is located) seems to fix the issue. Still looking into the reason why contribute permissions are required.

Comment: Are the news items being published?  It is the final step in the process.  If Approval is also required, the items must also be approved by someone with the appropriate permissions